# Confused about Constructor Chains in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've worked a fair amount with singleton classes in C++ (for a class), and now for a not-class project, I'm attempting to use inherited classes.

For some reason, I'm being really thick about constructor chains.

Consider the following:

```
class SuperClass
{
    string privateKey;
    string publicKey;
    string name;

public:
    enum Key {PUBLIC, PRIVATE};
    SuperClass(Key, string);
};

SuperClass::SuperClass(Key key, string theKey)
{
    switch(key)
    { 
        case PUBLIC: publicKey = theKey;
                     break;
        case PRIVATE: privateKey = theKey;
                     break;
    }
}


class SubClass : private SuperClass
{
public:
    SubClass(string key);
};

SubClass::SubClass(string key)
: SuperClass(SuperClass::PUBLIC, key) // "SubClass" will only interact with the public key, in this case.
{
    cout << "I'm instantiated!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    SubClass example ("thisIsThePublicKey");
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function ncall to SuperClass::SuperClass()
note: candidates are: SuperClass::SuperClass(SuperClass::Key, std::string)
```

Why do I get this? Haven't I used the constructor it says is a candidate?
I feel like I've read every tutorial on constructor chains, and I still don't get what I'm supposed to be doing differently.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Review the code in the question, or better simplify the actual code and post it directly. In the conversion you have not added the inheritance relationship and the modified code should not expose the behavior you talk about.

Comment: -1 and voted to close. Code provided here doesn't exhibit the problem reported in the question, and the answer accepted isn't relevant to the real problem, whatever that might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you forgot to inherit from your super class:

```
class SubClass
```

Should be:

```
class SubClass : public SuperClass
```

Comment: Sorry, that was bad transcription. My actual code reads: "class SubClass : private SuperClass"...changing the above to reflect. I do have it set to private so it can access "privateKey" and "publicKey"---shoudl I not have done that? Maybe I don't understand how private/public works in the inheritance context.

Comment: @TomThorogood with `private SuperClass` it compiles for me: http://ideone.com/d2XUR

Comment: Whilst to be fair the error message you are getting certainly seems a bit fishy for this to have been the problem, apart from this your code looks fine to me and in fact compiles here. Are you sure you don't have any other transcription errors, ie. a beneficial one?

Comment: @SethCarnegie Thanks for that. I may have to see if I have some ridiculous typo in my actual code, then. This is driving me crazy on this end. Maybe I'll just start over. I haven't gotten _that_ far. /grin.

Comment: @CharlesKeepax That's what I'm wondering. I'm going to re-write from scratch using the above as a template...

Comment: @TomThorogood The public/private on the inheritance indicates whether another class using SubClass can "see" that it's also a SuperClass. It gives SubClass no more ability to interact with private data members in SuperClass.

Comment: @CharlesKeepax Yep. That's exactly what it was. No idea where my error was, but it's gone now after re-writing. Thanks for testing! I really thought I was missing a core concept somewhere.

Comment: @ThatChuckGuy Thanks for the explanation there. It seems all the tutorials say, "Well get to this later."

Comment: @TomThorogood you can think of inheriting from a class as `private`, `protected`, or `public` as setting the "cap" or "ceiling" for the access specifiers of the members of the superclass. If you inherit from it `public`ly, then no access is changed because `public` is the most permissive access (the "highest ceiling"). If you use `protected`, the `public` members of the base are reduced to `protected` and everything else is left alone (it lowers the ceiling from `public` to `protected`). If you do `private`, everything is reduced to `private` (the "lowest ceiling").

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you've posted all the relevant code for your example, as the above code compiles for me with g++.

That said, however, I can guess from the error message that Subclass has a default constructor in it somewhere, or some other second constructor that you have not posted in your example yet, defined something like this:

```
SubClass::SubClass() // No argument constructor
{
    cout << "Default constructor (no initialization)." << endl;
 }
```

This will implicitly try to call the SuperClass::SuperClass() default constructor.  Usually C++ will generate a default constructor for you if you don't provide any constructors at all.  However, since you have defined a constructor that takes parameters for SuperClass, C++ won't generate a default constructor for it.

Another possibility is: you have created another subclass of SuperClass, with no constructors, and thus C++ is generating an implicit default constructor.  However, C++'s generated implicit constructor can't find a default SuperClass constructor to invoke.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I can't see in your SubClass definition where you specify the inheritance. It must be something like this for public inheritance:

```
class SubClass : public SuperClass
{
 // definition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must inherit from `SuperClass`:

```
class SubClass : public SuperClass
{
public:
    SubClass(string key);
};
```

Your example compiles also fine if I use private inheritance.